# Actualizar múltiples columnas en una misma tabla MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, array, formularios, update

Hola a todos estoy tratando de hacer una actualización múltiple en una misma tabla, tengo un formulario que primero que todo muestra todos los datos de la tabla, en este caso tengo una tabla llamada informacion_contenido_FAQ donde tiene 3 campos : ID , pregunta y respuesta, en el momento tengo 3 registros y como digo esos tres registros los muestro en un formulario en cada uno en un input y textarea así :

[image: Imagen que represento el formulario]

Cuando envío los datos me llega un array de la siguiente forma :

```
Array(
[pregunta-faq-1] => Who said that? SURE you can die! You want to die?!
[respuesta-faq-1] => Or a guy who burns down a bar for the insurance money! Why would I want!

[pregunta-faq-2] => Attempted murder? Now honestly, what is that? 
[respuesta-faq-2] => Fire can be our friend; whether it's toasting marshmallows or raining down on Charlie.

[pregunta-faq-3] => errrrr
[respuesta-faq-3] => qrrrr

[FAQ-checked] => 1
[formulario] => modificar-informacion-FAQ)
```

Como se ve todos los campos se envían con una referencia -1 , -2 , -3 ese numero lo coloco para identificar cada pregunta con su respuesta.

Mi pregunta es cómo puedo hacer una actualización conjunta o múltiple identificando los id de cada campo? 
Espero me hallan entendido, gracias.

Comment: Siempre son 3 preguntas? es decir siempre recibes pregunta-faq-1, pregunta-faq-2 y pregunta-faq-3? o el número es el id de la pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para recorrer tu array se me ocurre de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {//Recorremos la variable POST
    $idPregunta = (int)substr($key, -1); //Obtenemos el id
    if ($key[0] == 'p') //Verificamos si es pregunta
        echo "UPDATE cat_preguntas set pregunta = '$value' WHERE id = $idPregunta ".'<br>';
    else//Si es respuesta
        echo "UPDATE cat_preguntas set respuesta = '$value' WHERE id = $idPregunta ".'<br>';
}
```

El código resulta algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Yo te aconsejaría que mandaras tu post en forma de array, y utilizarás el id de la pregunta cómo índice, así sería más fácil de consumir y podrías hacer el update más rápido:

El name de tus input quedaría algo así:

```
<input name="pregunta[1][pregunta]" value="Who said that? SURE you can die! You want to die?!">
<input name="pregunta[1][respuesta]" value="Or a guy who burns down a bar for the insurance money! Why would I want!">
```

Con lo que obtendrías algo así:

```
array(1) {
  ["pregunta"]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["pregunta"]=>
      string(50) "Who said that? SURE you can die! You want to die?!"
      ["respuesta"]=>
      string(72) "Or a guy who burns down a bar for the insurance money! Why would I want!"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["pregunta"]=>
      string(46) "Attempted murder? Now honestly, what is that? "
      ["respuesta"]=>
      string(86) "Fire can be our friend; whether it's toasting marshmallows or raining down on Charlie."
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["pregunta"]=>
      string(5) "qrrrr"
    }
  }
}
```

Y para recorrerlo sería así:

```
foreach ($_POST["pregunta"] as $id=>$value) {//Recorremos la variable POST
    echo "UPDATE cat_preguntas SET pregunta = '$value[pregunta]', respuesta = '$value[respuesta]' WHERE id = $id".'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Manuel a tu respuesta, fue de gran ayuda, pude terminar mi problema, Mil gracias

Comment: De nada, cuando gustes